# Training LSTM in keras for classification, with data structure with 60 time steps

Tags: classification, lstm

I have a multidimensional dataset(3500,10), in which, there is one binary variable I want to predict, y (3500, 1). So I used the following code to separated X and y and create a data structure with 60 timesteps to use as input for the LSTM network:

```
data_set = data_set.as_matrix() # Using multiple predictors.

X_total = []
y_total = []

n_future = 1  # Number of days you want to predict into the future
n_past = 60  # Number of past days you want to use to predict the future


for i in range(60, len(data_set)):
    X_total.append(data_set[i-n_past:i, :9])
    y_total.append(data_set[i+n_future-1:i + n_future, 9])
X_total, y_total = np.array(X_total), np.array(y_total)
```

Then I get X_total(3460,60,9) and y_total(3460,1)

How can I be sure that the NN uses for each obs of X_total the matching y_total?
It is kind of confusing, when I look into X_total data, it seems that it starts at the first obs of the original data_set and y_total at the 60th.
How can I check it?